# How to show variables from PHP file in HTML file

Tags: php, html, templates

im having this function to call templates with .html extension from templates folder because i want to separate html from php

ok this is my function for calling template

```
class Template {

public $temp;

// function for reading the template from a directory
function gettemplate($template) {

    // check if path is folder
    if (is_dir('templates/')) {

        // check if file exists and if is readable
        if (is_readable('templates/' . $template . '.html')) {

            $this->temp = 'templates/' . $template . '.html';

            return $this->temp;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

This class calling template from templates folder

now what i need is to make example profile.html and profile.php

in profile.html just make variables like First name : `<?php echo $first_name; ?>`

and in profile.php to define varibales
here is profile.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {

$id     = $filters->validate_url($_GET['id']);
$data   = $users->userdata($id);
$id     = $data['user_id'];

$first_name = $data['first_name'];
$last_name  = $data['last_name'];
$username   = $data['username'];
$email      = $data['email'];
$country    = $data['country'];
$date       = $data['date'];

include ( $template->gettemplate('profile') );
```

and here is profile.html

```
<ul>
<li>First name : <?php echo $first_name; ?></li>
<li>Last name : <?php echo $last_name; ?></li>
<li>Username : <?php echo $username; ?></li>
<li>Email : <?php echo $email; ?></li>
<li>Country : <?php echo $country; ?></li>
<li>Member since : <?php echo $date; ?></li>
```

now my question is how do i make class to call template file just with

```
$template->gettemplate('profile');
```

and not with `include ($template->gettemplate('profile'));`

and to display variables from php file in html file

Comment: try googling for php template engine tutorial, or use an existing template engine and learn from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php%20%22)

### Question 1 - display variables from php file in html file

Use the `extract()` function " to display variables from php file in html file".  It will create a local variable with the name of the array key and the value of the array value

```
$data   = $users->userdata($id);
extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
include $template->gettemplate('profile');
```

### Question 2 - call template file just with `$template->gettemplate('profile');`

I don't believe there is a way to get around using an `include`. You could put the `include` in `gettemplate` and pass the data array.  There are several really good template engine on the net.  I recommend looking at a few.  I recommend looking at 
[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)